# How do I add css property for particular Div if class is found(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="b" >
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <div class="a"> 
     <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
   </div>
</div>
```

This is a piece of code in which I want to add css properties to div with class "b" if `<p>` contains `class="ABC"`.
How to do it?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("p.ABC").parents("div.b").css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b" >
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <div class="a"> 
     <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
   </div>
</div>
```

- `$("p.ABC")` this finds all the **p** elements has the class **ABC**.
- `parents("div.b")` finds the first parent that is **div** and has class named **b** of the selected element.
- `css()` adds the styles you want. You can also use `addClass()` method to add predefined class.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this helps

```
if($( "p" ).hasClass( "ABC" )) {
// if you want to add a class with many properties, then
$( "div.b" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
// if you want to add one property to existing class then the below statement
$( "div.b" ).css( "attribute-name", value );
}
```

You can add all the css properties in "yourClass"

```js
if($("p").hasClass("ABC")) {
$("div.b").css("color", "blue");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b" >
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <div class="a"> 
     <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
   </div>
</div>
```

Please check the code snippet.

I added a css property color as blue to the class 'b' if 'p' has 'ABC'. its working

Comment: if($( "p" ).hasClass( "ABC" )) {
$( "div.b" ).css(some properties);
} Can I use it like this. I am new to Jquery. I hope you understand

Comment: Yes, you can use. For example, if you want to add color to that class, then use  $( "div.b" ).css("color", "red")

Comment: What about padding?

Comment: You can add any property, if it is padding then it would be  $( "div.b" ).css("padding", "5px")

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Comment: I am unable to use it, changes aren't reflecting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("p.ABC")` to find all `<p>` with class `ABC` then `.closest(".b")` to find the parent div with class `b` then `.css()` to change css properties.

I recommend using `.addClass()` / `.removeClass()` rather than change css directly, but this helps you find the parent.

This also allows you to have multiple `div class='b'` in your html and it will only apply to the one with `ABC`

```js
$("p.ABC").closest(".b").css("background-color", "pink");
```

```css
.b+.b {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="DEF">ABC not present</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also turn it around using `:has`

```
$(".b:has(.ABC)").css("background-color", "pink")
```

which states: select all `.b` that has at least one child that has class `.ABC`, which is nearer to your concept of: add css to div with class "b" if `<p>` contains `class="ABC"`

So it depends on which way you want to work it.

```js
$(".b:has(.ABC)").css("background-color", "pink")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="DEF">ABC not present</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to look directly at `<p class="ABC">` and check if it has a class using [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/). Then you can traverse upwards to find the nearest element with `class="b"`

Something like this:

```
var elementToModify = $('p').hasClass('ABC').closest('.b');
elementToModify.prop('property', newValue);
```

Checkout these to further understand their use:

[prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest)